# Syntax for nested products and sums in AMPL optimization function

Tags: optimization, syntax, ampl

I'm having trouble indexing over a set.
For some reason, I am getting a syntax error for the square bracket inside my sum for `sum {i in {1..n_paths}} P[i];`.

I'm able to display the set `{i in {1..n_paths}}`, and `P[1]` or any other legitimate `i`, but I'm not formatting the sum expression correctly somehow.

```
ampl: param n_paths;
ampl: set P {1..n_paths};
ampl: display sum {i in {1..n_paths}} P[i];

syntax error
context:  display sum {i in {1..n_paths}}  >>> P[ <<< i];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, P is an an indexed collection of sets, which means that each `P[i]` is itself a set. For example:

```
reset;
param n_paths := 2;
set P{1..n_paths};

data;
set P[1] := 1 2 5;
set P[2] := 6 5 1;
```

Here, `display P[1];` returns `set  P[1] := 1 2 3;`.

If I try evaluating `sum{i in 1..n_paths} P[i]`, I'm asking AMPL to add the set {1,2,3} to the set {6,5,1}, and the `sum` of two sets isn't defined. If I want to add up all the members of `P[1]` through `P[n_paths]` then I need a double sum:

```
display sum{i in 1..n_paths} sum{j in P[i]} j;
# caution: this will fail if we have non-numbers in our sets
```

This returns 20: 1+2+5 from `P[1]` added to 6+5+1 from `P[2]`.

I could also merge the sets before summing:

```
display sum{j in union{i in 1..n_paths} P[i]} j;
```

Because `union` discards the duplicated values, this ends up summing 1, 2, 5, and 6 to get 14.